# Best way to determine if one image is in others - opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I understand that you can use `SURF` and `FLANN` to match `descriptors` on images as shown in the [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html), but my question is can you compare a large selection of images against one and get a definite output telling you which ones match, and which ones don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that one image is(maybe) a part of another image, you can use template matching. It can get matches between an image patch and an input image.

Here is the official tutorial:

[Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#template-matching)